# curved shadow disappears with background-color

Tags: css

I want a curve horizontal shadow, it works, but the background-color affects to shadow

I have this html:

```
<div class="dcontainer">
  <div class="dshadow curva curva-h">
    myshadow
  </div>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
.dcontainer {
    /*background-color: #f6f6f6;*/
    height: 140px;
}
.dshadow {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:40%;
padding:1em;
margin:2em 10px 4em;
background:#fff;
box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.dshadow:before,
.dshadow:after {
content:"";
position:absolute;
z-index:-2;
}

.curva:before {
top:21px;
bottom:10px;
left:0;
right:50%;
box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
border-radius:10px / 100px;
}

.curva-h:before {
top:50%;
bottom:0;
left:10px;
right:10px;
border-radius:100px / 10px;
}
```

if I uncomment background-color the shadow "curva" disappears, what happen???
I don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the `z-index` of your container to make it lower than the shadow - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fkgmj/)

```css
.dcontainer {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -5;
}
```

Comment: how it's possible? z-index with position:relative?? but it works!