# Not getting shadow for the div in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I was testing to create 3-d shadow like below

[image]

But I am not getting any shadow.Can anyone tell me why?Here is the home.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer_div">
    <div class="box effect2">
      <h3>Effect 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the style.css code.

```
#outer_div{
background-color:#f7f7f7;
width:300px;
height:200px;
}

.box h3{
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
top:80px;
}
.box {
width:150px;
height:100px;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
margin-left:80px ;
padding:30px 0 0 0;
}

.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
 transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
 .effect2:after
 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
 transform: rotate(3deg);
 right: 10px;
 left: auto;
  }
```

Actually the problem arises when I set background to outer div.Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place one image over another in CSS 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321971/how-to-place-one-image-over-another-in-css-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described over here: [curved shadow disappears with background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348917/curved-shadow-disappears-with-background-color) you can try to adjust the z-index of the container by adding

```
position:relative;
z-index:-2;
```

to #outer_div

Comment: :Thanx!Ii worked.Though I tried `z-index` but `position:relative`was missing .Thanx again.

Answer (score 4):

you need to do some css changes

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hf5k/)

```
#outer_div{
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box h3{
    text-align:center;
}
.box {
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    padding:50px 0 0 0;
}

.effect2{
    position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width:300px;
    background: #777;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
   transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
   transform: rotate(3deg);
   right: 10px;
   left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler version using only 2 DOM elements (and my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haltersweb/Nt8wM/1/)):

```
<div class="shadow-box">
    <h1>effect 1</h1>
</div>

h1 {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    top: -1ex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.shadow-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.shadow-box:before, .shadow-box:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 13px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow:  0px 10px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.shadow-box:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.shadow-box:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

Comment: Note that this version only requires two DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something along these lines. Your outer_div is hiding the :before and :after content of the effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/9FBTx/2

```
<div id="outer_div">
    <div class="box effect2">
      <h3>Effect 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>

#outer_div{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}

#outer_div:before, #outer_div:after
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 5px;
    top: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -33px;
    content: "";
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

#outer_div:after {
    left: auto;
    right: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
    transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

Comment: :Its not working.I want shadow of inner_box over gray background.